# If $H$ is a projection matrix and $J$ is a matrix of ones, is it always true that $HJ = J$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

I'm trying to prove that if $H$ is a projection matrix and $J$ is a matrix of ones, is it always true that $HJ = J$?

For example,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm not sure if this is true in general. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The question is equivalent to asking whether $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is always an eigenvector of a projection matrix. This is clearly false, since that vector may not be preserved by the projection – take $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ for example.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$A small random counter-example for which $\,H=H^2\;$ but $\;HJ\ne J$
$$\eqalign{
H &= \frac{1}{693}\m{
404 & 34 & 340 \\
34 & 689 & -40 \\
340 & -40 & 293 \\
} \qquad
HJ &= \frac{1}{693}\m{
778 & 778 & 778 \\
683 & 683 & 683 \\
593 & 593 & 593 \\
} \\\\
}$$
Note, however, that $\,HJ = \LR{H\o}\o^T = h\o^T$

So the product in question is always a rank-$\tt1$ matrix with constant rows.